# how to get full QueryInterfaceRequest sql string in grdb including all arguments (GRDB.StatementArguments) in the string

Tags: swift, grdb

I need to get full sql query of query interface in order to save them in user defaults but i couldn't find this functionality

update:
in order to achieve full query string:

1. including arguments that were trimmed by sqlite for injection you can not replace those arguments with question mark manualy.
2. you can not achieve real value of those arguments because they are private

Answer (score 2):

There is a `trace` function in the latest GRDB:

```
// Prints all SQL statements
var config = Configuration()
config.prepareDatabase { db in
    db.trace { print($0) }
}
```

Comment: Follow link in the other answer if you're not sure where to put the above code

Answer (score 1):

The [How do I print a request as SQL?](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-print-a-request-as-sql) FAQ says:

> You can turn your request into a SQLRequest instance:
>
> ```
> try dbQueue.read { db in
>     let request = Wine
>         .filter(Column("origin") == "Burgundy")
>         .order(Column("price")
>
>     let sqlRequest = try SQLRequest(db, request: request)
>     print(sqlRequest.sql)
>     // Prints SELECT * FROM wine WHERE origin = ? ORDER BY price
>     print(sqlRequest.arguments)
>     // Prints ["Burgundy"]
> }
> ```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer.
i know this but in order to achieve full query string including arguments that were trimmed by sqlite for injection you can not replace those arguments with question mark manualy.another cons is you can not achieve real value of those arguments because they are private

Comment: OK @nova. Next time you ask a question on SO, will you please make sure you tell what you already know, so that both the question and answers are better focused? This will help everybody, not only you. Now your comment is about something else. I suggest you ask another question, or, if some feature is missing, open a Github issue.

Comment: Good Point. i will update the question, i didn't know it from the time when i asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of GRDB, the answer is different.

taken from  [How do I print a request as SQL?](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-print-a-request-as-sql) :

```
try dbQueue.read { db in
    let request = Player.filter(Column("email") == "arthur@example.com")
    let statement = try request.makePreparedRequest(db).statement
    print(statement) // SELECT * FROM player WHERE email = ?
    print(statement.arguments) // ["arthur@example.com"]
}
```